# How to edit css : Bigcommerce Stencil

Tags: bigcommerce

How can I edit in CSS.

In Stencil framework can't found .css file.

In assets folder only found .scss file.

I want to edit in theme.css

How can I edit ?

Can any body help me ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is really unclear. Please describe the problem a bit more - as it stands, this is not answerable.

Comment: SCSS is a css file that uses sass. http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: If my answer helped you can you mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing a stencil theme locally and have ran `stencil start` it watches your SCSS files. So one option is you could add any custom CSS you want to the `/assets/scss/theme.scss` file.

Another option is you could create your own SCSS file, say for example `custom.scss`, and place it in `/assets/scss/`. Then import it to your `theme.scss` like this `@import "custom"` . Make sure you place it at the bottom of your `theme.scss` file so it overrides any css you are wishing to alter.

Answer (score 0):

the .scss files are the css files. The stencil framework uses scss instead of the regular css.

This link should help guide you on how to edit the files: https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Using-the-Stencil-Theme-Editor

Comment: This is link as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

the .scss files are the css files. The stencil framework uses scss instead of the regular css.
Please check this path `/assets/scss/theme.scss`

Comment: HI Maciej!     .scss is not same css but his same work!